# React Delete Button Todolist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello guys im having a bit of trouble with this, I have found some topics on here but none seem to be helping anyways this is my problem. I need to create a delete button as well as a delete todo method on the app components using an array of .filter, and then pass it to the ToDo component as a prop, as well as Add an onClick event listener to the delete button, and have it call deleteTodo, passing it the index of the to-do.

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ToDo from './components/ToDo.js';
class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     todos: [
       { description: 'Walk the cat', isCompleted: true},
       { description: 'Throw away the dishes', isCompleted: false},
       { description: 'Buy new dishes', isCompleted: false}
     ],
     newTodoDescription: ''
   };
 }



 handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({ newTodoDescription: e.target.value })
 }
 handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (!this.state.newTodoDescription) { return }
   const newTodo = { description: this.state.newTodoDescription, isCompleted: false};
   this.setState({ todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo], newTodoDescription: ''});
 }

 toggleComplete(index) {
   const todos = this.state.todos.slice();
   const todo = todos[index];
   todo.isCompleted = todo.isCompleted ? false : true;
   this.setState({ todos: todos});
   }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
                    { this.state.todos.map( (todo, index) =>
              <ToDo key={ index } description={ todo.description } isCompleted={ todo.isCompleted } toggleComplete={ () => this.toggleComplete(index) } />
            )}
          </ul>
          <form onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e) }>
          <input type="text" value={ this.state.newTodoDescription } onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e) } />
          <input type="submit" />
          </form>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }


export default App;
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class ToDo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
                <li>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.props.isCompleted } onChange={ this.props.toggleComplete } />
                 <span> { this.props.description }</span>
                 </li>

    );
  }
}

export default ToDo;
```

Comment: Share your research. What other topics have you found? Maybe take a step back and explain more clearly what it is, exactly, you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new method `deleteTodo` in `App` that takes in the `todo` object you want to remove and filter that out from the state.

Since the order of `todos` will now change, you can no longer use the array index as `key` for the `Todo` components. You can add an `id` to your todo objects and use that instead.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    todos: [
      { id: Math.random(), description: "Buy new dishes", isCompleted: false }
    ],
    newTodoDescription: ""
  };

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ newTodoDescription: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.newTodoDescription) {
      return;
    }
    const newTodo = {
      id: Math.random(),
      description: this.state.newTodoDescription,
      isCompleted: false
    };
    this.setState({
      todos: [...this.state.todos, newTodo],
      newTodoDescription: ""
    });
  }

  toggleComplete(todo) {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.map(t => {
        if (t !== todo) {
          return t;
        }
        return { ...t, isCompleted: !t.isCompleted };
      })
    });
  }

  deleteTodo(todo) {
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.filter(t => t !== todo) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
            <ToDo
              key={todo.id}
              description={todo.description}
              isCompleted={todo.isCompleted}
              toggleComplete={() => this.toggleComplete(todo)}
              deleteTodo={() => this.deleteTodo(todo)}
            />
          ))}
        </ul>
        <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={this.state.newTodoDescription}
            onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
          />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ToDo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <li>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={this.props.isCompleted}
          onChange={this.props.toggleComplete}
        />
        <span> {this.props.description}</span>
        <button onClick={this.props.deleteTodo}>Delete</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```